# как хранить энергонезависимую переменную python

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня в программе нужно хранить небольшую переменную чтобы она не теряла свое значение при выключении программы/компьютера обязательно ли для этого использовать базу данных или есть другие более простые способы?

Comment: файл на диске..

Answer (score 0):

```py
# открыть файл для записи и для чтения
file_write = open('путь/к/файлу/для/переменной', 'w')
file_read = open('путь/к/файлу/для/переменной', 'r')

# записать что-то в переменную-файл
file_write.write('информация')

# сохранить и закрыть
file_write.close()

# получить значение "переменной"
file_read.read()
print(file_read.read()) # вывести файл на экран

# закрыть файл для чтения
file_read.close()
```